# What song goes like this? (not really...)

Tags: knowledge, music

What? I gave you the main idea.

> It it it it it it it
> It it it it it it it
> It it it it it it it
> It it it it it Automation
>
> Robotics
> Telecommunications
>
> It it it it it it it
> It it it it it it it
> It it it it it it it
> It it it it
> Machinery
>
> Computers
> Thomas and Manuel's remix
> Jack's remix
> Applied science
>
> Automation
> Robotics
> Mechanization
> Industrial science
>
> Applied science
> Telecommunications
> Machinery
> Mechanics
> Computers

Comment: I can't believe daft punk haven't already made this song

Comment: juicifer, daft punk made this song!

Comment: @poco if that's relevant, maybe a "knowledge" tag is appropriate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The song is:

> *[Technologic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technologic)* (2005) by [Daft Punk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daft_Punk)

There are three things to note about the lyrics given here...

> 1. The series of 'It's each represent the verses of the song with all the verbs removed - for example, the first verse goes:
>
>  *Buy it, use it, break it, fix it, trash it, change it, mail, upgrade it
>
>  Charge it, point it, zoom it, press it, snap it, work it, quick erase it
>
>  Write it, cut it, paste it, save it, load it, check it, quick rewrite it
>
>  Plug it, play it, burn it, rip it, rip it*
>
>  Once these are removed, only the 'It's remain.
>
>  2. Almost every other word in this puzzle (e.g. Automation, Robotics, telecommunications...) is a kind-of synonym of 'Technologic', the repeated refrain to the Daft Punk song.
>
>  3. The exception to this is the section marked as "Thomas and Manuel's remix Jack's remix". In the Daft Punk song, the lyric here is "Daft remix, Jaxx remix". Here, the OP has merely obfuscated 'Daft' using the forenames of the duo (**Thomas** Bangalter and Guy-**Manuel** de Homem-Christo) and 'Jaxx' using a soundalike.